# C# LINQ Join Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

```
SELECT     PART_TYPE.PART_TYPE_ID,
           PART_TYPE.PART_TYPE_NAME,                       
           PART_AVAILABILITY.DATE_REF, 
           PART_TYPE.VEHICLE_ID,
           PART_AVAILABILITY.AVAIL_COUNT

FROM  PART_AVAILABILITY
RIGHT JOIN PART_TYPE
ON PART_AVAILABILITY.PART_TYPE_ID = PART_TYPE.PART_TYPE_ID
AND PART_AVAILABILITY.VEHICLE_ID = PART_TYPE.VEHICLE_ID 
where PART_TYPE.VEHICLE_ID = 366
```

`PART_TYPE_ID` and `VEHICLE_ID` are `Primary Key` in `PART_TYPE` table.
`VEHICLE_ID` is a `Foreign Key` from `VEHICLE` table.

`DATE_REF`, `PART_TYPE_ID` and `VEHICLE_ID` are `Primary Key` in `PART_AVAILABILITY` table.
`VEHICLE_ID` and  `PART_TYPE_ID` are `Foreign Key` from `PART_TYPE` table.

Above query gave below output.

```
PART_TYPE_ID    PART_TYPE_NAME  DATE_REF                 VEHICLE_ID  AVAIL_COUNT
5               A1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
6               B1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         2
7               C1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
8               D1              NULL                     366         NULL
9               E1              NULL                     366         NULL
16              F1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
```

This my `linq` query for above sql query.

```
var vehiclePartType = from pa in context.PART_AVAILABILITY
                    join pt in context.PART_TYPE
                    on pa.PART_TYPE_ID equals pt.PART_TYPE_ID into joined
                    from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where j.VEHICLE_ID == 366
                    select new
                    {
                        PART_TYPE = j,
                        PART_AVAILABILITY = pa
                    };
```

But linq query gave below output.

```
PART_TYPE_ID    PART_TYPE_NAME  DATE_REF                 VEHICLE_ID  AVAIL_COUNT
5               A1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
6               B1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         2
7               C1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
16              F1              2013-06-20 00:00:00.000  366         1
```

`NULL` records are missing.

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Join in LINQ is done by reversing join statements so correct one would be this:

```
var vehiclePartType = from pt in context.PART_TYPE
                      join pa in context.PART_AVAILABILITY on pt.PART_TYPE_ID equals pa.PART_TYPE_ID into joined
                      from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where pt.VEHICLE_ID == 366
                      select new
                      {
                          PART_TYPE = pt,
                          PART_AVAILABILITY = j
                      };
```

Comment: Getting error as `The name 'pa' does not exist in the current context` from `PART_AVAILABILITY = pa` in `Select`

Comment: Fixed, please try again :)

Comment: no. i have tried this before. this is also return output in my question. `NULL` records are missing.

Comment: Okay, now it should be fixed. Changed where clause as that was what filtered out nulls :)

Comment: Thanks :). I want to filter result with `DATE_REF` in `PART_AVAILABILITY` table. so i added line as `&& j.DATE_REF == dt` after `where` clause. (`dt` is `DateTime` object). then again `NULL` records are missing. what is the issue ?

Comment: That because when `j` is null then that check fails. That should work (needs testing) `(j == null || j.DATE_REF == dt)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32316/discussion-between-bishan-and-gzaxx)

Answer (score 1):

I think You have to swap your tables. Actually what you are doing is left join . To convert into right just swap the tables Like::

```
  {
                      var vehiclePartType = from 
                        pt in context.PART_TYPE join pa in context.PART_AVAILABILITY
                        on pt.PART_TYPE_ID equals pa.PART_TYPE_ID   into joined
                        from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where j.VEHICLE_ID == 366
                        select new
                        {
                            PART_TYPE = j,
                            PART_AVAILABILITY = pa
                        };
    }
```

Comment: Getting error as `The name 'pa' does not exist in the current context` from `PART_AVAILABILITY = pa` in `Select`

Answer (score 0):

I am not too much familier with LINQ but in your SQL query you have

`AND PART_AVAILABILITY.VEHICLE_ID = PART_TYPE.VEHICLE_ID`

This is missing in your LINQ query.

Comment: SQL query returns above data with out that part. so that is not the issue.